# Find function not working until table modified

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I was wondering if anyone can assist at all please.

I have created a `userform` within Excel and using a reference number it will return the values of the given row within a table. The issue I am currently receiving is when I initially open the workbook that the find function does not work and comes back with the `Msgbox` given in the code "ID does not exist".

However if I use the `userform` to create a new line within the table then after this the find function is working absolutely fine. Has anyone got any suggestions?

```
Private Sub Find_Click()

Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String

mysearch = Me.Search.Value

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Data")
    Set searchRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    Me.RsnDc = foundCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    Me.BDM.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
    Me.MIns.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
    Me.EUs.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
    Me.In.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 9).Value
    Me.Pr.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
    Me.Qu.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 11).Value
    Me.ReCd.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 12).Value
    Me.ReOrCd.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 13).Value
    Me.Ttl.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
    Me.Va.Value = Me.Total.Value / 1.2
    Me.VT.Value = Me.Total.Value - Me.Value.Value
    Me.R.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 17).Value
    Me.App.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
    Me.L1.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
    Me.L2.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 20).Value
    Me.CY.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 21).Value
    Me.PC.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 22).Value
    Me.SN1.Value = Left(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 2)
    Me.SN2.Value = Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 3, 2)
    Me.SN3.Value = Right(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 2)
    Me.ANCT.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 24).Value
Else
     MsgBox "ID does not exist."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint before the find command, and make sure that all your variables are being set without the form having loaded first. My suspicion is that since you are referring to "Me.Search.Value" there is something in your form that is preventing this from being set, and thus mysearch wouldnt be referring to anything. The immediate and locals window will be a great help to you in debugging this.

Comment: Is Me.Search a textbox?  If adding a new row makes it work, then expand your search area by one row and see if it works.   -- .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)+1)

Comment: @BrandonBarney thanks for your suggestion and John. Brandon using your suggestions allowed me to narrow down the issue considerably. Thank you

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I commented out all of the other text boxes and removed "Me" from the "Search.Value"  and it works fine.  So it's either in the "Me" or somewhere in your list of other textboxes.  Try commenting them out half at a time to narrow it down.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim mysearch As String

mysearch = Search.Value

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Data")
    Set searchRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
'    Me.RsnDc = foundCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
'    Me.BDM.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
'    Me.MIns.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
'    Me.EUs.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
'    Me.In.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 9).Value
'    Me.Pr.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
'    Me.Qu.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 11).Value
'    Me.ReCd.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 12).Value
'    Me.ReOrCd.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 13).Value
'    Me.Ttl.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
'    Me.Va.Value = Me.Total.Value / 1.2
'    Me.VT.Value = Me.Total.Value - Me.Value.Value
'    Me.r.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 17).Value
'    Me.App.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
'    Me.L1.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
'    Me.L2.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 20).Value
'    Me.cy.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 21).Value
'    Me.pc.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 22).Value
'    Me.SN1.Value = Left(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 2)
'    Me.SN2.Value = Mid(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 3, 2)
'    Me.SN3.Value = Right(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 2)
'    Me.ANCT.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 24).Value
Beep
MsgBox "FOUND IT!"
Else
     MsgBox "ID does not exist."
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to have been that in the search range column A was using a formula to dictate the search criteria. I have now built this into the userform and it seems to work a dream. Thanks for your time guys.